# jQuery UI auto-complete auto-suggestion list does not change

Tags: php, jquery, json

Below are my code for jQuery UI, the problem I am facing is that no matter what the user inputs it immediately displays everything in the array and not just the words close to the inputs.

main file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="jqui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqui/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tags").autocomplete({source:"result.php"});
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

result file

```
<?php
$arrResults = array('orange', 'apple', 'bannana');
// Print them out, one per line
echo json_encode($arrResults);    
?>
```

Comment: Do you mead your auto complete list is not going to filter according to what you are typing?

Comment: yes thats what I mean exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
$req = $_GET['term']; //first get the search keyword as get method

$arrResults = array('orange', 'apple', 'bannana');

$array = array_filter($arrResults, 'mycallback');
//filter the array containing search word using call back function

function mycallback($var)
{
    global $req;
    if(preg_match('/^'.$req.'/', $var))
    {       
        return $var;
    }
}

$array1 = array();

//filter null array
foreach($array as $arr => $val)
{
        if(!empty($val))
        {
                $array1[] = $val;
        }

}

//echo out the json encoded array
echo json_encode($array1);
```

Comment: I think this kind of work is already included in jquery itself ?

Comment: @Jayantha well not sure ... but this seems to solve the problem.

Comment: thanx this worked, but I had hoped that maybe there could be a simpler method

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({source:"result.php", dataType:"json"});
```

Comment: @Kay:Im sorry, that parameter should be `dataType` not type.

Comment: @Kay: can you see what exactly is returned by result.php? you can try manually formatting the output to look like array in string format. eg:`["one", "two", "three"]`..