# jQuery Autocomplete Input Box

Tags: php, jquery, json

So I created an auto complete box using jQuery and PHP to pull the content from the database, and it's working fine, except when I go to type in the input box it pulls back all the results, instead of the results similar to what I'm typing.

So if you type **Test** it pulls back:

```
This
is
a
Test
```

Instead of displaying

```
Test
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="group_name" name="group_name">
```

**Here is the jQuery I'm using**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#group_name" ).autocomplete({
              source: "/wuzhapnn/php/data_stream/group_names",
              select: function(event, ui) { 
              $("#f").submit(); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is my php page**

```
if ($_GET['run'] == 'group_names') {
    // pulls live data from database
    $db = db_open();
    $query = "SELECT group_name FROM groups";
    $result = db_query($db, $query);
    if (db_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        $result = db_fetch_all($result);
        foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
            $group_names_array[] .= $value['group_name'];
        }   
    } else {

    }

    echo json_encode(array_values(array_unique($group_names_array)));  
}
```

- **Recent Updates**

**New jQuery**

```
<script>
    var availableName;

    $.getJson('/wuzhapnn/php/data_stream',function(response){
        availableName = response;
    });

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#group_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableName,
              select: function(event, ui) { 
              $("#f").submit(); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**New PHP Page**

```
if ($_GET['run'] == 'group_names') {
    // pulls live data from database
    $db = db_open();
    $query = "SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%'";
    $result = db_query($db, $query);
    if (db_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        $result = db_fetch_all($result);
        foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
            $group_names_array[] .= $value['group_name'];
        }   
    } else {

    }

    echo json_encode(array_values(array_unique($group_names_array)));  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `LIKE` clause.

```
"SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%'";
```

because `"SELECT group_name FROM groups"` this will give all the result from `database` but you need only those who match with typed words so use `LIKE MySQL` clause.

**Other Person Comment Response.**

if you want to create json object before use it you can do it as below,

```
var availableName;

$.getJson('/wuzhapnn/php/data_stream/group_names',function(response){
   availableName = response;
});
```

after this just use below code for autoComplete.

```
$( "#group_name" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableName ,
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the functionality. He is returning all the group_names as a json object, which will be used by the autocomplete jquery ui to find a match.

Comment: Yes, and that page is a json object of all group_names, which is what it should be.

Comment: I did find a script on here that seems to be doing it for others, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the global $_GET['term'] with json. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529356/1661548

Comment: @ChristianRankin if jeemusu is right then you need to create json object before and call it inplace of url that you have in source

Comment: I could send over the value of the input box live to my data_stream.php in the url?

Comment: @Jeemusu i know that page is json object but you know that page will return all the data not searched data...get it.?

Comment: I think what I'm missing is where is the value inside TYPEDWORD coming from?

Comment: @ChristianRankin TYPEDWORD is the text that are typed in textbox..you can see it in firebug...mostly its $_GET['term']

Comment: I added my source code to my question above.. It's not working still, and I wanted you to see how I have it.

Comment: @ChristianRankin make sure data base has more than one matching record.

Comment: @ChristianRankin just use `echo json_encode($group_names_array); `

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP snippet doesn't actually use the value sent by the autocomplete plugin.
If you are using JQuery's [plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) then the value send is a GET parameter called *terms*.

This needs to be included in your PHP.

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
```

You then need to include that in your query something like the following, **but first please escape this value before using it directly in an SQL statement**.

```
SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE group_name LIKE %<term>%
```

Comment: I have a function setup to escape strings, lol. I'm not that much of a n00b! :)

Comment: So if jQuery already uses this value, it's being set without me having to do anything?

Comment: Ok, great on the escaping.  Yes the value is already being sent to your PHP script.  If you view the Remote Datasource example at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote search "spar" and watch the network traffic using Firebug or Developer Tools, you will see that the term parameter is automatically sent through.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working right

**New jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function() {       
        $( "#group_name" ).autocomplete({
          source: "/wuzhapnn/php/data_stream",
          minLength: 2,
        });
      });
</script>
```

**New PHP** (thanks to Dipesh Parmar)

```
// pulls live data from database
$db = db_open();
$query = "SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%'";
$result = db_query($db, $query);

    $result = db_fetch_all($result);
    foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
        $group_names_array[] .= $value['group_name'];
    }   


echo json_encode(array_values(array_unique($group_names_array)));
```